# Analyze system memory/cpu stats with Java

Tags: java, jsp, unix, google-visualization

I want simple results like Total Memory, Free Memory, CPU Usage,etc on my Unix system.
Currently I am using the shell command `top`.

**Is there any functionality in Java for doing the same thing ?**

My goal is to display the results in a web app via Google Gauge Charts. So obviously, it would be much easier for me to go with Java, instead of executing Unix commands from within Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = 
    ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

for (Method method: operatingSystemMXBean.getClass ().getMethods ()) 
{
    method.setAccessible (true);
    String methodName = method.getName ();
    if (methodName.startsWith ("get")
        && Modifier.isPublic (method.getModifiers ())
        && OperatingSystemMXBean.class.isAssignableFrom (
            method.getDeclaringClass ())) {
        try
        {
            System.out.println (
                methodName.substring (3) + ": " + 
                method.invoke (operatingSystemMXBean));
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            // Ignore
        }
    }
}
```

The output is different on different operating systems and versions of Java.  Here is output for JDK 1.7 on Linux:

```
FreeSwapSpaceSize: 2172059648
FreePhysicalMemorySize: 1757573120
CommittedVirtualMemorySize: 26741071872
MaxFileDescriptorCount: 8192
OpenFileDescriptorCount: 4
ProcessCpuLoad: 2.0251808355598717E-10
ProcessCpuTime: 60000000
SystemCpuLoad: 0.03673989450920194
TotalPhysicalMemorySize: 101439979520
TotalSwapSpaceSize: 4294950912
Name: Linux
ObjectName: java.lang:type=OperatingSystem
AvailableProcessors: 12
Arch: amd64
SystemLoadAverage: 1.86
Version: 2.6.32.54-0.3-default
```

Value `SystemLoadAverage` is the same as `load average` reported by `top` command.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is happening from this stage - OperatingSystemMXBean.class.isAssignableFrom

Comment: Interface `java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean` defines only few methods, while real implementation of this interface in JRE usually have much more methods, so I use reflection to discover them at run time.  I iterate over all public non-static methods of the object returned by `ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean()` and invoke methods that 1) have name starting with `get` and 2) are defined in some class that implements `OperatingSystemMXBean` interface.  The second condition helps me to avoid non-relevant methods such as `Object.getClass()`.

Comment: There are a lot of information about system mem, but not cpu. I can only see **ProcessCpuTime** and **AvailableProcessors**, which is not enough to find CPU% in use right ?

Comment: When I run it on Linux, it outputs `SystemLoadAverage` parameter that is the same as `load average` reported by `top`.  Not sure what this parameter means exactly.